# PHP Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php

When i add select form field in elementor and try to save i get an error message.The code below is where the issue is

```
private function maybe_truncate_log() {
    /** @var Log_Item[] $log */
    $log = $this->get_log();

    if ( Log_Item::MAX_LOG_ENTRIES < count( $log ) ) {
        $log = array_slice( $log, -Log_Item::MAX_LOG_ENTRIES );
    }

    return $log;
}
```

Comment: the error seems clear, what do you think `$log` is ? you can check with `var_dump($log)`

Comment: `get_log()` isn't returning what it's supposed to be. You need to check that function and see what's going wrong there. If you add some other code to only check the count if `$log` is countable, you may end up covering up a problem rather than solving it.

Answer (score 0):

This error occur when your array `$log` sometime may be empty or null so you should a check before using it in `count` function. check code below.

```
if(!empty($log)){
   if ( Log_Item::MAX_LOG_ENTRIES < count( $log ) ) {
        $log = array_slice( $log, -Log_Item::MAX_LOG_ENTRIES );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks. I tried this fix but I still get the error and can't save the form page

Comment: When i use radio buttons I'm able to save the page. But when it's the select/dropdown field the error comes up

Comment: Please add form html in your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
$log = $this->get_log();
$log = json_decode(json_encode($log), true);
```

This will transform $log from object to array.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is self explanatory, to make it straight here's the code that should work:

```
private function maybe_truncate_log() {
    /** @var Log_Item[] $log */
    $log = $this->get_log();
    if(is_array($log)){
       if ( Log_Item::MAX_LOG_ENTRIES < count( $log ) ) {
         $log = array_slice( $log, -Log_Item::MAX_LOG_ENTRIES );
       }
    }

    return $log;
}
```